# Neural Network for Handwritten Numbers

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition

My first approach at this had no involvement with neural networks. I would simply compare the handwritten input(numbers 1-3) to a model image where it would compare pixels of both images via the index and see if they hold the same RGB value. This method works poorly and would only work if the handwritten number had pixels in common with the base image. Now I want to implement some sort of neural network but I have some questions.

All images consist of all black or white pixels and each image is 500x500 pixels.

I have a basic understanding of Neural Networks where there is back propagation, bias, weights, hidden layers, etc... I understand what they do abstractly but I'm perplexed as to how I would implement a neural network. What are patterns that the computer can recognize?

I want to note that I'm not limiting myself to Neural Networks, I'm open to other solutions to this problem but neural networks seem like a good way to approach this.

Comment: No answer (as the question might be too broad), but NVIDIA is working on stuff like this (among others). Particularly, the https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn library basically ships with a single sample, which is a classification program for http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Comment: There is no limit on the kind of patterns a NN can learn. Of course it's important to have enough data. I would not recommend implementing your own NN implementation, but to use well-tested libraries. We don't know what language you are using, but one of the most (and still super-powerful) beginner-friendly libs is [keras](https://keras.io/) (python) which also has a good starting template for the MNIST-problem mentioned by Marco [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py). There are other MNIST-examples. Modern research will teach you:use **convolution nets!**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked... after modifications. Your neural network is probably doing poor job, because you take pixels's colour intensity as feature vector, directly. That makes them very sensitive to shifts (e.g. shifting image by one pixel will result in completely different vector). Try normalizing the image with respect to the characters' positions and sizes. Also think if you could use some other pieces of information from the image for supplement the feature vectors.
PS. Why wouldn't you convert RGB scale to simply gray? Visually you get the same information, but you'll get 3 times less features to train on.